# How to enable debug output for the Minimal Download Strategy (MDS)?

Tags: 2013, 2016, mds

I need to know why [MDS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/minimal-download-strategy-overview) failover for a SharePoint page is triggered.

In the browser address bar I see *start.aspx* when loading a page (as expected), then the browser is redirected to the actual page URL (without *start.aspx*). That means the MDS engine detected a page that cannot be served via MDS.

Now I need to know why this happens. I remember some time in the past seeing lots of MDS-related debug messages in the browser console. But if I look today (SP 2016) there is nothing.

How can I see/enable debug output for MDS to have more insight into what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

The ULS log contains entries pointing to the cause of the MDS failover.

In my case:

> Message: MDSFailover: script in markup

This is written as *Verbose* message with area *SharePoint Foundation* and category *Unified Logging Service*.

This can also be seen in the [developer dashboard](https://knowledge.zomers.eu/SharePoint/Pages/How-to-enable-the-SharePoint-2010-Developer-Dashboard.aspx), no need to go to the server.